# Set custom response headers in aws lambda integration

Tags: aws-lambda

How do we set custom integration response fetched from method request.

the code used in cloud formation script.

```
    ResponseParameters:
    method.response.header.Content-Type: "'application/json'"
    method.response.header.X-B3-Trace-Id: "method.request.header.BodId"
    method.response.header.BodId: "method.request.header.BodId"
```